# Spring MVC and HTTP Url Connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an API, which is going to save an Employee in to the DB which I have call from my Java console application.

url: http://localhost:8070/applications/employees (type: POST)

Function looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/applications/employees/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private @ResponseBoyd Map<String,Object> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    ....Code to save an Employee
}
```

In my Java console application, I am sending request with the help of HttpUrlConnection

```
private void saveEmployee(Employee employee){
    String SAVE_EMPLOYEE = "http://localhost:8070/applications/employees";
    URL saveEmployee = new URL(SAVE_EMPLOYEE);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) saveEmployee .openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod(HTTP_POST);
    // MY DOUBT HERE IS HOW DO I PASS THE EMPLOYEE OBJECT
}
```

The doubt here is how do I pass my Employee object?

Comment: Instead of using HttpURLConnection on the client side you could use springs resttemplate - https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-spring-resttemplate-0 - then all the serialization stuff us handled for you

Comment: @anders agree... thanks a lot.. it worked using Spring REST Template :)